# Cache your own components using The Flash Player Cache

Tags: flash, caching, actionscript

Ted [talks of a "Player Cache"](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2007/06/flex-3-thursday-dramatically-smaller.php) existing within *Flash Player 9.3* that allows the Flex components to be reused *across domains*.

It would be an extra-benefit if my components can be reused across my multiple websites.

1. Is this Flex only? *(all code passed thru the Flex 3 compiler "mxmlc")*
2. Will Flash AS2 components be cached as well?
3. Will Flash AS 3 components be cached as well? *(compiling via the Flash IDE)*
4. Can my own components be cached? (or is the Adobe-propitiatory only?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Only Adobe can create signed Runtime Shared Libraries, and only signed RSLs can be stored in the Flash Player cache. If you create an RSL that contains a custom library, it will be unsigned. You cannot sign it." My only addition to that would be, "…yet."

**Knowing Adobe, if you ask loudly enough, the company finds a way.**

by [Tom Ortega II](http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/april2008/articles/article6/)

Answer (score 2):

> For the player cache, only signed
>   Adobe platform components, such as
>   Flex, can be cached.

[Emmy Huang](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2007/06/flex-3-thursday-dramatically-smaller.php),
Product Manager, Adobe Flash Player

Comment: What's with all the Jeremy-answer-hate?

Answer (score 2):

if you create your own code library in a swf external to the main swf, this will be cached by the browser for all requests to the same host, so multiple swf files using the same code library on the same host will benefit from this. In the case of signed RSLs, effectively, Adobe is allowing their common code base to be shared across domains, for which a very high level of trust must be assumed. I can't see much reason to require this for your own code, and would view any leniency on Adobe's policy as a security risk.

edit:
With the right crossdomain policies in place, there's no reason why you could not have a code library shared across multiple domains.

Answer (score 1):

The what and how of the [Flash Player Cache](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flash_Player#Flash_Player_cache), from Adobe Labs.

Answer (score 0):

The flash player is not properly managing new content. It is still pulling old information from the cache when something changes on the server. Is there a way to avoid this?